# Why is my code terminating if a child function fails and not continuing?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out when a call to a child function errors, the entire process terminates.

here's my main function:

```
Public Function Update_SP_Request_Lists()

    '::-- Initialize --::'
    Call Initialize_Global_Content
    
    '::-- Purge Tables --::'
    If strEnvType <> "[PROD]" Then Call Purge_Table_Contents
            
    'Run all Functions
    Call Update_rdInvestments
    Call Update_rdAssets
    Call Update_rdTarget
    Call Update_rdActivity
    Call Update_rdPlatIntInfa
    Call Update_Indications
    Call Update_rdDevice
    Call Update_rdPPStarget
    
End Function
```

And then for instance, here is Update_rdActivity, which if has an error, terminates everything:

```
Public Function Update_rdActivity()

'::-- Error Handler --::'
On Error GoTo Proc_Err
    
    '::-- Initialize --::'
    Call Initialize_Global_Content
    
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
    
    Dim sRS As DAO.Recordset, tRS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field2
    
    Dim i As Integer, z As Integer
    
    Dim sTable As String, tTable As String, strMask As String, strNameSub As String
    Dim tgtStr As String, tmpStr As String, tFlds As String, sFlds As String, vCriteria As String
    Dim tFld() As String, sFld() As String, vStr() As String
    Dim ReqVals As String, ReqVal() As String
    
    Dim strFunctName As String, strStartTime As Date, strEndTime As Date, strTimeDiff As String
    Dim strStep As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String, strTo As String, strProcError As String
    
    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set db = ws.Databases(0)
    
    'Start a transaction to ensure all updates are run or rolled back
    ws.BeginTrans: strTFlag = 1
    
    strFunctName = "Update_rdActivity": strStartTime = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    strMask = "PFP*"
    sTable = "MDM_Project_Portfolio_Reference"
    tTable = "rdActivity"
    strNameSub = "Name"
    
    tFlds = strNameSub & ",[Parent_Node],[Alias],[Phase],[Time_Tracking],[Research_DDU],[Project_Type],[PrePostCS],[Status],[Direct_Indirect],[Model_Flag_CMC],[Model_Flag_PRD],[Model_Flag_DEV],[Device_PFD_Link]"
    sFlds = "Name,[Parent Node],[Alias],[Phase (Nominal)],[Time_Tracking],[PRD_DDU],[ProjectType],[PrePostCS],[PFP Status],[Direct Flag],[ASC_CMC_MODEL_T],[ASC_PRD_MODEL_T],[ASC_DEV_MODEL_T],[Device_PlatformID]"
                             
    strTList = "": strSList = ""
    strTQryR = Replace(tFlds, strTList, ""): strSQryR = Replace(sFlds, strSList, "")
 
    strFldsQry = sTable & Replace(strSQryR, ",", ", " & "[" & sTable & "].")
    strFldsQry = Replace(strFldsQry, sTable & "Name", "[" & sTable & "]" & "." & "[" & "Name" & "]")
        
    tFld = Split(tFlds, ",")
    sFld = Split(sFlds, ",")
                
    ReqVals = ",,,,,,,"
    ReqVal = Split(ReqVals, ",")
    
    strStep = "Step 0: Purge Data Elements in Table that don't exist in Source"
    strSQL = "" & _
            " DELETE *" & _
            " FROM [" & tTable & "] t" & _
            " WHERE NOT EXISTS " & _
                    " ( SELECT 0" & _
                    "   FROM [" & sTable & "] s" & _
                    "   WHERE t.[" & strNameSub & "] = s.Name )" & _
                    "   AND [RequestStatus] = 'Published';"
    'db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    
    strStep = "Step 1: Add New Data Elements"
    strSQL = "" & _
            "INSERT INTO [" & tTable & "] (" & _
                strTQryR & ",[RequestStatus],[Workflow_Notify],[BPR_Flag],[Deactivate_Flag]" & _
            " )" & _
            " SELECT" & _
                strFldsQry & _
                " ,'Published','Notified','1',Switch([" & sTable & "].Alias like '*(DO NOT USE)*','Yes',[" & sTable & "].Alias Not LIke '*(DO NOT USE)*','No')" & _
            " FROM [" & sTable & "]" & _
            "LEFT JOIN [" & tTable & "] ON [" & tTable & "].[" & strNameSub & "] = [" & sTable & "].[Name]" & _
            " WHERE [" & sTable & "].[Name] LIKE '" & strMask & "'" & _
                " AND [" & tTable & "].[" & strNameSub & "] IS NULL;"
    db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    strStep = ""
    
    'Clear Variables
    strStep = "": tgtStr = ""
    
    'Open a table-type Recordset
    'Return codes that have been changed only over the last 4 days
    'Set sRS = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from [" & sTable & "] where [Name] like """ & strMask & """", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set sRS = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [" & sTable & "] WHERE [Name] LIKE """ & strMask & """" & _
                               "AND Format( [Last Changed On],""yyyymmdd"") >= Format(Date()-" & strSynchAge & ",""yyyymmdd"")", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set tRS = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [" & tTable & "] WHERE [RequestStatus] = ""Published""", dbOpenDynaset)
        
    Do Until sRS.EOF
    
        ReqVal(0) = Split(sRS.Fields("Last Changed On").value, " ")(0)
        ReqVal(1) = Nz(sRS.Fields("Last Changed By").value, "MDM Admin")
        ReqVal(2) = sRS.Fields("Name").value
        ReqVal(3) = sRS.Fields("Alias").value
        ReqVal(7) = "dl-mdmsupport@takeda.com"
    
        tgtStr = ""
        
        If tRS.Fields("RequestStatus").value <> "Updated" _
            And tRS.Fields("RequestStatus").value <> "New" _
            And tRS.Fields("RequestStatus").value <> "Approved" Then
        
            vCriteria = "Name = '" & sRS.Fields(strNameSub).value & "'"
            tRS.MoveFirst
            tRS.FindFirst vCriteria
            
            If Not tRS.NoMatch Then
    
                'Do Standard field mapping property updates
                For i = 0 To UBound(tFld)
                
                    'Set fld to check .IsComplex property
                    Set fld = tRS(tFld(i))
                    
                    strStep = "Step 2: Update Data Element Attributes" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                              "Data Element - " & Nz(tRS.Fields(strNameSub).value, "") & vbNewLine & _
                              "Source Field - " & Nz(sFld(i), "") & vbNewLine & _
                              "Source Value - " & Nz(sRS.Fields(sFld(i)).value, "") & vbNewLine & _
                              "Target Field - " & Nz(tFld(i), "") & vbNewLine & _
                              "Target Value - " & Nz(tRS.Fields(tFld(i)).value, "")
                    
                    'Ignore MVF Attributes
                    If Not fld.IsComplex Then
                        If Nz(tRS.Fields(tFld(i)).value, "foo") <> Nz(sRS.Fields(sFld(i)).value, "foo") Then
                        
                            ReqVal(4) = Replace(Replace(tFld(i), "[", ""), "]", "")
                            ReqVal(5) = Nz(tRS.Fields(tFld(i)).value, "No Value")
                            ReqVal(6) = Nz(sRS.Fields(sFld(i)).value, "No Value")
                            Call Add_Request(ReqVal)
                            
                            tRS.Edit
                            tRS.Fields(tFld(i)).value = sRS.Fields(sFld(i)).value
                            tRS.Update

                        End If
                     End If
                Next
                                
            End If
            
        End If
        sRS.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    'commit all changes
    ws.CommitTrans: strTFlag = 0
    
Proc_Exit:

    '::-- Update Table with Procedure Information --::'
    strEndTime = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    strTimeDiff = strEndTime - strStartTime
    Call ADD_RUN_TIMES( _
                        strFunctName, _
                        strStartTime, _
                        strEndTime, _
                        Hour(strTimeDiff) & " hours " & Minute(strTimeDiff) & " minutes " & Second(strTimeDiff) & " seconds", _
                        Switch(strProcError = "", "Success", Not (strProcError = ""), "Failed"), _
                        strProcError _
                       )
    
    On Error Resume Next
        If Not sRS Is Nothing Then sRS.Close
        If Not tRS Is Nothing Then tRS.Close
        
        Set sRS = Nothing
        Set tRS = Nothing
        Set tRSMV = Nothing
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
    
    Exit Function

Proc_Err:

    '::-- Rollback Transaction --::'
    If strTFlag = 1 Then ws.Rollback
    
    '::-- Capture VB Error --::'
    strProcError = Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    
    strSubject = "WARNING : Function '" & strFunctName & "' Failed " & strEnvType
    strBody = Switch(strStep = "", "", Not (strStep = ""), strStep & vbNewLine & vbNewLine) & _
              "VB Error : " & strProcError & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "VB Profile : " & CurrentUser() & vbNewLine & _
              "Database : " & strCPN
    strTo = strMDMSupportEmail
    Call MDM_Routines.Email_Utility(strSubject, strBody, strTo, "", "")
    
    Resume Proc_Exit
    
End Function
```

Can someone help me figure out why? I would like it to process all child functions regardless of error.  Thank you.

Comment: Try commenting out `Call MDM_Routines.EMailUtility` in `Proc_Err` and see if it still terminates everything.

Comment: Each child method will need to have its own error handling otherwise the error propagates to the calling method (main).

Comment: So interestingly enough, MDM_Routines.EMailUtility does not have error handling.  Could that be my reason?  But even so, the EmailUitlity is not throwing an error, so why would that be the reason?

Comment: An error that occurs in the error handler would be a problem and cause the symptoms you are seeing.  From the docs:  `If an error occurs while an error handler is active (between the occurrence of the error and a Resume, Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement), the current procedure's error handler can't handle the error.`

Comment: Hi all - thank you for your suggestions!  Adding error handling to ALL subs/functions used in my ETL solved the problem.  Appreciate the feedback, I learned something new!